# How to handle multiple domains for one service/product?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, search-results, multiple-domains

I am wondering how to setup (SEO- and SERPs-wise) a product launch with multiple domains. Lets say I have product X and it's an answer for subject A, subject B and subject C. `www.example.com` is were the sales are happening, but as the product name is a fantasy name I guess it won't have much organic traffic. But subject A, B and C are more likely to have organic traffic depending on the written copy per subject of course.

My question is, should I attempt to write good SEO/SERP copy for subject a, b and c and have a link to `www.example.com` or should I just use a Redirect 301 from subject a, b and c to `www.example.com`.
(PS I also thinking of registering domains A,B and C so competitors can't registered them)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your question is more complex than you realize. You are making the assumption that having multiple domains is a good idea. Often, it is not with some exception. As well, you are assuming that you can build value to a domain and then 301 redirect to another. This often does not work as easily as people think.

Granted that your product has a new and unique name. But what I think you are missing is the concept of brand building which would mandate putting the product name and brand first and foremost. ***Yes you are right in a very clever way!*** You also need to tie the product into usage and that is likely a major focus too.

I am not knocking your ideas, they are not too far off, but rather I an trying to wake you to some ideas that you may not have considered.

Here are some answers I provided that may formulate a better understanding (ignore the titles):

[Multiple domains (for multiple brands) redirecting to different pages of a website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71403/multiple-domains-for-multiple-brands-redirecting-to-different-pages-of-a-websi/71407#71407)

[If Google penalizes main domain, will it affect subdomain too?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71353/if-google-penalizes-main-domain-will-it-affect-subdomain-too/71354#71354)

[How my website will be ranked if I host multilanguage blogs under my domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71307/how-my-website-will-be-ranked-if-i-host-multilanguage-blogs-under-my-domain/71321#71321)

The up-shot is that it is better to have a single domain most of the time unless the topics are divergent and/or non-complementary. As well, 301 redirects remove value for the domain that is designed to attract users and dividing work over several domains divides potential more times than not.